# Repeat a span element 20 times in SharePoint view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I'm heavily customizing view of a SharePoint list using JSON formatting, a gantt-like timeline, a roadmap. I would like to split the timeline with 20 vertical lines over it. Currently I have done it manually, adding 20 fitted span elements over it. I recognize this is a terrible approach:

```
{
   "elmType": "span",
   "style": {
      "position":     "absolute",
      "border-right": "1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1)",
      "height":       "43px",
      "left":         "100px"
    }
},
{
   "elmType": "span",
   "style": {
      "position":     "absolute",
      "border-right": "1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1)",
      "height":       "43px",
      "left":         "200px"
    }
},
{
   "elmType": "span",
   "style": {
      "position":     "absolute",
      "border-right": "1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1)",
      "height":       "43px",
      "left":         "300px"
    }
},
...
```

I studied the documentation for the [forEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#foreach) function but all the examples use an existing object as the loop source such as

```
"forEach": "region in @currentField"
```

I think I should do something like this this, but it seems as if this syntax is wrong, it causes the view to fail to render and it turns blank white:

```
{
   "elmType": "span",
   "forEach": "month in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]",
   "style": {
      "position":     "absolute",
      "border-right": "1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1)",
      "height":       "43px",
      "left":         "=([$month] * 100) + 'px'"
    }
},
```

[image]

Comment: Try using `"left": "=([$month] * 100) + 'px'"`. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Good catch! Unfortunately that was a typo only in this post, not in the source code where I do have the equal sign in place. And I tried to review my post thoroughly to avoid anyone losing their precious time looking into these types of mistakes... :/

Comment: check my answer below and try to use JSON in given format in example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` operator to properly create an array of numbers. Then based on it you can use `forEach` in JSON.

Try to construct your JSON in below example format:

**JSON**:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "forEach": "choiceIterator in split('0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19',',')",
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "[$choiceIterator]",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-bgColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-white",
        "title": "='I am the letter ' + [$choiceIterator]"
      },
      "style": {
        "width": "16px",
        "height": "16px",
        "text-align": "center",
        "margin": "1px"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Reference**: [Multi-Choice forEach](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/blob/master/column-samples/multi-choice-foreach/multi-choice-foreach.json)

Comment: Thank you. Split() was the solution.